# using pagination to output array

Tags: php

this is my code

```
//select all the members id
$result = mysql_query("select id from member");

//create array of ids
$id = array();

// page is the number of my pagination numbering and its from 1 to 10
$dis = $page;// for example $page = 1

// $page get its value every time a user click my pagination numbering i.e $page = $_GET[page]; 
// guess you understand

while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //id is my field name
    $id[] = $u_id[id];
}

echo $id[$dis];
```

my problem is that this above code works for only 4 records out of 10records. my question is, why is it not working outputin other ids when the array index is 4,5... and howw do i amke it work

secondly the echo part is just the test of my idea but what i wanted to do is to pass the return id to a function for query. please any help

Comment: That's quite unreadable. Please get rid of the extraneous backticks. Mark code as code by indenting it four spaces.

Comment: Good work with that, @prodigitalson.

Answer (score 2):

Well not sure if this is your problem but you might want to correct this if its not just a type in your post:

```
while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id[] = $u_id['id']; // this should be 'id' not $id
}
```

Comment: no this is what i meant sorry for the mistake               while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id[] = $u_id[$dis]; 
  }

Comment: while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id[] = $u_id[$dis]; // that is a mistake
}

Comment: while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id[] = $u_id['id']; //id is my field name yes you are right sorry once again
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have:

```
while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id[] = $u_id['id']; // changed from $id inside brackets
}
```

Comment: while($u_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $id[] = $u_id['id']; //id is my field name yes you are right sorry once again }

Answer (score 0):

For starters, as you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, your `$u_uid` variable will not contain any numeric indices. In fact, it will only *ever* have an `'id'` key so your while loop should really look like this

```
$id[] = $u_uid['id'];
```

This will build the `$id` array with *every* id in your `member` table which is probably not what you want. As you mention pagination, I expect you actually want something like this

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$page = max(1, $page); // ensure page is 1 or greater

$rowCount = 5; // you can set this to whatever you want
$offset = ($page - 1) * $rowCount;

$result = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT id FROM member ORDER BY id LIMIT %d, %d',
        $offset, $rowCount));
```

Comment: thanks , i have my pagination working fine but for example my pagin number 1 2 3 4 5.   i want output the value of my array while pages number will i.e 1 2 3 4 5 serve as my array index any time the user click on the next link of my pagin list